# Simple carry bit

Tags: math, assembly, carryflag

Ok so I am revising for a test One of the revision questions is:

If

- R4 = FEh
- R5 = DCh
- R6= ABh
- Carry = 0

What are the contents of `A` and `Carry` after the following code:

```
MOV A,R6 
SUBB A,R4 
SUBB A,R5
```

The correct answer is `Carry = 1` and  `A = D0h`

I can work out what the registers are, but I can't get the correct answer for the carry bit. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Which assembly language? The question hinges on how SUBB is defined, i.e. how it handles the carry flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first subtract is AB - FE => AD
Since FE > AB the carry bit is set

The second subtrract is AD - (DC + 1) => DO
Since DD > AD the carry bit is set again.

Comment: I The one thing I was missing was adding the carry bit on...cannot believe I didn't see that...thank you so much, saved me from hours of being confused.